# How to ensure that the data in the consumption Kafka is not lost

Tags: mysql, go, apache-kafka, high-availability

1. Now my server is comsuming the message from kafka.
2. Then I send the message to a channel and MarkMessage(auto commit).

```golang
func (h MsgConsumerGroupHandler) ConsumeClaim(sess sarama.ConsumerGroupSession, claim sarama.ConsumerGroupClaim) error {
    for msg := range claim.Messages() {
            h.msgQueue <- msg
            // it will autocommit
            sess.MarkMessage(msg, "")
    }
    return nil
}
```

3. Worker goroutine for-range the channel and send to processing function(like Insert database).

The question is how can I ensure that the data in the channel is not lost when the server is broken.

I have a plan now:
Whenever I plug a message into the database,I record the offset of the message at the same time.
If the service goes down, when I restart, I read the databaseto obtain the final offset and set in Kafka to re-consume.

Is it right?

Comment: https://newrelic.com/blog/best-practices/kafka-consumer-config-auto-commit-data-loss turn off auto-commit if you want to be sure the message is handled.

Comment: Kafka can handle its own offsets fine. Do you really need a database?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes,i am